# PD регулятор для движения к цели

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть робот, я знаю его координаты `[x1, y1]` и угл `phi`, робот может двигаться к цели, которая имеет координаты `[x2, y2]`. Сейчас я просто вычисляю угл

```
theta = math.atan2(x1-x2, y1-y2)
```

потом смотрю на разницу углов, если theta - phi = 0 или меньше какого-то эпсилон, то угловая скорость движения робота нулевая `angular_velocity = 0`, а если нет, то то робот поворачивается право `angular_velocity = -1` или влево `angular_velocity = 1`, линейная скорость всегда постоянна. Проблема в том, что робот двигается зигзагом и траектория движения робот больше похоже на ломанную, чем на ровную линию, а если уменьшить скорость поворота, то робот будет слишком медленно поворачивать и ему нужно слишком много места для разворота. Я так понял мне нужен ПД регулятор. Очень хотелось бы в ответе увидеть примеры такой реализации с точки зрения именно программирования, потому что теорию я почитал, но все примеры были для регулятора температуры, а не для угловой скорости.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первую очередь введите пропорциональность (П) - скорость поворота не 1, а `V = P*(theta - phi)`, где P - коэффициент, который нужно подобрать.

Если не устроит, добавляйте дифференциальный член c коэффициентом D, учитывающий реальное угловое ускорение

```
delta = theta - phi
V = P * delta + D * ddelta/dt
```

То, что используется угловая скорость, а не мощность нагревателя, принципиально задачу не меняет, однако тепловая проблема осложняется большим временем отклика (в механической системе тоже могут быть подобные эффекты из-за момента инерции и т.п.)

Comment: Не очень понял как считать ddelta/dt?

Comment: Измерять угловую скорость через промежутки времени, эта производная - отношение изменения скорости к промежутку времени `(theta(t2) - theta(t1)) / (t2-t1)`

Comment: Ну, вроде, получилось. Правда, всё равно иногда делает резкие повороты, но уже не так часто.